# How to get the RMSEA value after a Factor analysis (psych:fa) with R?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I did a factor analysis on a database using the **fa** function of the R **psych** package :

```
facto <- fa(df)
```

I managed to retrieve the RMSEA with facto$RMSEA :

For example :

| RMSEA | lower | upper | confidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.08014526 | 0.07886056 | 0.08162674 | 0.90000000 |

But I would like to retrieve **only the first value** (0.08). Do you know how to access it ?

I don't see the wanted value in the [fa function Rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.2.9/topics/fa)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering the answer. The RMSEA value is here :

```
facto$RMSEA[["RMSEA"]]
```